# Можно ли в отладчике Chrome установить breakpoint с условием?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, отладка

В разделе Watch можно добавлять переменные и объекты. А возможно ли, чтобы выполнение было остановлено при определенном условии, например i > 7 или изменилось значение поля объекта (ctx.status к примеру изменился) ?
В разделе Breakpoints можно только галочкой убирать/оставлять строку, как добавить условие какое-то не нашел.

Comment: `if(...){
<your code>
}`

Брикай <your code>, видимо, это и есть ответ на твой вопрос

Comment: @EgorRandomize нет, это не ответ на его вопрос. В отладчиках можно вешать свои условия, вне кода, на точку остановки. Его вопрос в том, можно ли так же сделать в dev tools chrome.

Comment: Да, именно в этом вопрос